# Extended ASCII character C++

Tags: c++, ascii, extended-ascii

Why can't I test for the ASCII value I assign to symbol (250) in this code? It seems weird to be testing for -6 when that is not what I assigned to symbol.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char symbol = 250; // dot symbol

    int a = symbol;

    cout << symbol << endl; // Outputs dot symbol

    cout << a << endl; // Outputs -6

    if(symbol == 250)
        cout << "250 works";

    if(symbol == -6)
        cout << "-6 works"; // -6 test works

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `symbol == '.'`?

Comment: 250 just happens to be what I am using, and I have a few other characters from extended ASCII in my bigger piece of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char` is signed on your platform. 250 is out of range for a signed character. You want:

```
if (symbol == static_cast<char>(250))
```

Otherwise `symbol` will be promoted to an integer. Alternatively, use `unsigned char` instead of `char` which may or may not be signed.

Comment: Thank you. I actually don't know the difference between signed and unsigned datatypes, but at least I know there is a difference in range.

Comment: For an unsigned datatype of the same width, one bit is used for the sign. So a one-byte unsigned can go from 0 to 255 while a one-byte signed can go from -128 to 127. In C++, plain old `char` can be either signed or unsigned. If it matters which to your code, you better specify the one you're expecting.